Animation featuring DC's Adam Strange saving planet Rann from a solar-powered war machine
I'm trying to find an animation featuring DC's Adam Strange, in which he saves the planet Rann (I think) from a supposedly unstoppable war machine, which turns out to have one weakness: it's powered by solar energy or radiation from the planet's sun.
I'm not sure if it's a standalone movie or part of a TV series. I'm 99% certain that it was American-made and in the English language, rather than an anime.
I think that it was from the 2010s?

DC Showcase: Adam Strange
The May 19, 2020 film, DC Showcase: Adam Strange, matches several key elements:

The story involves the planet Rann.
While there isn't a solar-powered war machine, there is a significant threat to a colony that Adam Strange helps defend against.

The film presents Adam Strange's origin story and his quest to return to Rann. Here's a brief overview:

Adam Strange's origin story is presented in flashbacks. On the planet Rann, a Thanagarian armada invaded and attacked. Strange's Rannian wife Alanna was killed in the missile strike, and he began searching for his daughter Aleea, in the process being teleported to Eden Corp Mining Colony Number 75 by a Zeta Beam.

There is a significant battle against alien invaders:

The colonists are attacked by bug-like aliens from underground, and the foreman attempts to ask Strange for help, but he is too drunk to do anything, so they leave him in a shelter for safety. When Strange sobers up and see the colony under attack, it reminds him of the attack on Rann and he decides to help.


I took the liberty of fleshing out your answer with more details about how this film addresses the question. Feel free to [edit] if I've misinterpreted anything.

Now that the answer has been improved by @galacticninja, I've upvoted this one.

"That's going to make it seem like the answer is incorrect" - For all we know, it may very well be, unless you tell us why it's correct. You being the asker unortunately matters squat with regards to the "100% correct"ness of the answer.

Also (after a certain amount of time) you can accept your own answer.
